# How to output regular numbers in multi-cursor state in vscode?

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code

Let's say I want to call a function 10 times quickly:

step1: Write ten fn(1)

step2: Use the multi-cursor to select the `parameters 1` of these ten functions

[image]

But then I don't know what to do, because I can't make the first one be 1, the second one be 2, the third one be 3...

Or is there a syntax like [Emmet](https://docs.emmet.io/)(`div{$}*3`) in js file?

Comment: why not write a for loop to call `fn(i)`, a lot easier if you need to do it 1..100

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the extension [Regex Text Generator](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=rioj7.regex-text-gen)

Use the command `Generate text based on Regular Expression`

- for match regex use: `.*`
- for generator expression use: `{{=i+1}}`

Answer (score 1):

As of v1.66 it won't be necessary to use an extension at all for simple replacement (0, 1, 2, ... or 1, 2, 3, ...) like this.  New snippet variables

```
$CURSOR_INDEX or ${CURSOR_INDEX}
$CURSOR_NUMBER or ${CURSOR_NUMBER}
```

are being added (they are in Insiders now).  So your snippet could be as simple as (inserted here via a keybinding in `keybindings.json`):

```
{
  "key": "alt+i",                       // whatever keybinding you want 
  "command": "editor.action.insertSnippet",
  "args": {
    "snippet": "$CURSOR_NUMBER"
  },
  "when": "editorTextFocus && editorHasMultipleSelections"   // if you want to restrict it
},
```

[image: increment integer for each cursor position]

You can't do any real math on the added numbers other than increment from 0 or 1.  To do more interesting math see below extension.

---

Using an extension that I wrote this is very easy: [Find and Transform](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ArturoDent.find-and-transform).

Create this keybinding (in your keybindings.json):

```
{
  "key": "alt+y",                   // whatever keybinding you want
  "command": "findInCurrentFile",
  "args": {
    // "find": "1",            // actually not necessary
    "replace": "${matchNumber}",
    "matchCase": true              // match only APPLE, not Apple
  }
}
```

That will replace whatever word your cursor is on with the `matchNumber` starting at 1.  If you wanted to start at 0, use `${matchIndex}`.

If you need to specify a more complicated regex find, you can do that too.